# display: table: increasing height of a table cell causes padding in other cells

Tags: html, css, padding, vertical-alignment

I am using `display: table` and `display: cell` to have 3 column layout with equal heights.

Here's my code,

**HTML:**

```
<div id='wrapper'>
 <aside class='column'>Left sidebar</aside>
 <div id='main' class='column'>
     <textarea rows="2"></textarea><br>Main content <br>
     <br><br><br>
 </div>
 <aside class='column'>Right sidebar</aside>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#wrapper {
    display: table;
}
aside {
    background-color:#EEE;
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
}
.column {
    display: table-cell; 
}
```

**JS**

```
$('textarea').focus(function () {
    $(this).attr('rows',8);
});
```

Here's the [demo](http://jsbin.com/welcome/72642/edit)

Now,

When I focus on `textarea`, height of `textarea` increases, and thus the height of `div#main` increases too. This adds a `padding-top` to both `aside`'s.

I am not sure if `display:table` and `display:cell` is the reason behind it, but I am not able to figure out the issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While I was writing this question, I figured out the issue, so sharing it to help others.

By default, the html element with `display: cell` has `vertical-align: middle`.

So, whenever `height` of one cell increases, content of other cell shifts because of `vertical-align:middle`. ( It was not a padding-top but vertical-alignment at middle of cell )

So, to fix the issue,

I added this to my css,

```
.column {
    display: table-cell; 
    vertical-align: top;
}
```